# Input password for putty pscp

Tags: copy, putty, pscp

I'm trying to execute below command using Putty  pscp tool.

> pscp -v -pw mypassword "X:\data\temp*" root@172.x.x.x:\tmp\data

I'm getting following error.

> Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available

I have to pass user name and password. And on target system I don't have much of control.

Could anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Once there, please include a complete pscp output. Also mention if you are able to login to the server using any other SCP/SFTP/SSH client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed 
    ...
    PermitRootLogin     no
    ...
    PasswordAuthentication  no
    ...

To

```
...
PermitRootLogin     yes
...
PasswordAuthentication  yes
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The remote server might be rejecting ssh with a password.  You could try to set up DSA or RSA keys with puttygen but you would need to change the key on the remote site.  Does this work with ftp?  Root login might also be disabled, and besides its usually a bad idea.  That is why someone suggested that this go to the superuser forum.  Root is not a regular user and remote login might be disabled in /etc/sshd_config.